# Sorting a range with multiple columns one of them containing a date prior to 1900

Tags: excel, vba

I would like assistance to carry out, in vba, the sorting of a range containing several columns. One of these columns contains a date prior to 1900. One of the sorting arguments should be the year of this date. The date is in the form dd/mm/yyyy.
Could a forum member help me WITHOUT creating a temporary column?
Thanks in advance
Gihem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Excel can only handle dates between `1900-01-01` and `9999-12-31` you must use a helper column. Actually your "dates" before `1900` are no real dates they are strings (text) and therefore are sorted alphabetically.

If you use the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format `yyyy-mm-dd` an alphabetical sort of strings would work. But therefore **all** dates need to be converted to strings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
The suggested solution suits me perfectly, all dates being before 1900 (a genealogical survey).